# How do I duplicate/copy a database from one user to another on the same host?

Tags: oracle-19c

I have a oracle se2 database and I want to duplicate a database do a different user in the same host (for testing data migration stuff). I created the user and gave it all the privileges required, but I'm uncertain on what's the best way to copy the data.

I tried exporting the db as well as copying it directly to the new one using sql developer, but it takes hours (the database is huge) and my connection gets timed out.

I assume there's a faster and safe way to do that internally on oracledb, but I'm not familiar enough with it. I've looked up the different tools that people recommend on other questions such as rmap, using pumps, etc, but it seems overly complicated, most questions I find are +8 years old and I don't know if they are obsolete, and from what I see it's generally used to copy DBs between different hosts.

For context my oracledb experience is running tests on oracle DBs using psycopg2 and querying stuff with sqlplus.

Any recommendations?

Comment: First question: what do you mean by "db"? Do you mean an entire Container Database (CDB), a Pluggable Database (PDB), or simply a *schema* within a CDB or PDB database instance?

Comment: If you are copying *just data* and not physical db files, then the answer is DataPump (expdp/impdp). You won't find anything faster.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-17FAE261-0972-4220-A2E4-44D479F519D4